# How to solve : Kivy Android OscService : app crashes with class not found error

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am trying to make a simple kivy app that uses oscpy and plyer to send notifications while the app is running in background (using a service).
However, my app crashes with this error :

> stderr: jnius.jnius.JavaException: Class not found 'org/kivy/oscserv/ServicePong'

Here is my main.py :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import datetime
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.utils import platform
from oscpy.client import OSCClient
from oscpy.server import OSCThreadServer
from plyer import notification

SERVICE_NAME = u'{packagename}.Service{servicename}'.format(
            packagename=u'org.kivy.oscserv',
            servicename=u'Pong'
)

class MyLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.setB=Button(text="set",size_hint=(.25,.2),pos_hint={"x":.3,"y":.4})
        self.add_widget(self.setB)
        self.setB.bind(on_press=self.set)
        self.lis=[]

        self.server=None
        self.server=server=OSCThreadServer()
        server.listen(
            address=b'localhost',
            port=30002,
            default=True
        )
        server.bind(b'/message',self.passnow)
        server.bind(b'/date',self.passnow)
        self.client=OSCClient(b'localhost',3000)
        self.start_service()
        self.stop=Button(text="Stop",size_hint=(.25,.2),pos_hint={"x":.3,"y":.1})
        self.add_widget(self.stop)
        self.stop.bind(on_press=self.stop_service)

    def start_service(self):
        if platform=='android':
            from jnius import autoclass
            service=autoclass(SERVICE_NAME)
            self.mActivity=autoclass(u'org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
            argument=''
            service.start(self.mActivity,argument)
            self.service=service

        elif platform in ('linux','linux2','macos','win'):
            from runpy import run_path
            from threading import Thread
            self.service=Thread(
                target=run_path,
                args=['service.py'],
                kwargs={'run_name':'__main__'},
                daemon=True
            )
            self.service.start()
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(
                "service start not implemented on this platform"
            )

    def stop_service(self):
        if self.service:
            if platform=="android":
                self.service.stop(self.mActivity)
            elif platform in ('linux','linux2','macos','win'):
                self.service.stop()
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError(
                    "service start not implemented on this platform"
                )
            self.service=None

    def set(self,button):
        time=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        if int(time.split(':')[1])+1 not in self.lis:
            self.lis.append(int(time.split(':')[1])+1)
        q=[]
        for p in range(len(self.lis)):
            if self.lis[p]==60:
                self.lis[p]=0
            if self.lis[p]<=int(time.split(':')[1]) and self.lis[p]!=0:
                q.append(p)
        for p in q:
            self.lis.remove(self.lis[p])
    #    print(self.lis)
        self.client.send_message(b'/ping',list(self.lis),)

    def passnow(self,message):
        pass

class PlyerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__=="__main__":
    now=PlyerApp()
    now.run()
```

And then here is the service.py:

```
import datetime

from oscpy.server import OSCThreadServer
from oscpy.client import OSCClient
from plyer import notification
from time import sleep

notiflis=[]

CLIENT = OSCClient('localhost',3002)

def ping(*args):
    lis=[k for k in args]
    global notiflis
    notiflis=lis
    print(lis)
    CLIENT.send_message(
        b'/message',[],
    )

def plyer():
    now=int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S").split(":")[1])
    #print(now,"   ",(now in notiflis))
    if now in notiflis:
        notification.notify(
        title=str('REMINDER AT '+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))),
        message="HERE IS YOUR REMINDER",
        timeout=15
        )
        notiflis.remove(now)
    else:
        return

if __name__=="__main__":
    SERVER = OSCThreadServer()
    SERVER.listen('localhost',port=3000,default=True)
    SERVER.bind(b'/ping',ping)
    while True:
        plyer()
        sleep(.9)
```

And here is the android.txt/buildozer.spec file :

```
title=<notiftrial>
package.name=<oscserv>
package.domain=<org.kivy>
source.dir=<src>
version.filename=%(source.dir)s/main.py
author=<pk>
orientation=<portrait>
requirements=<python3,kivy,kivymd,plyer,oscpy,pyjnius,jnius>
services=Pong:service.py
p4a.branch=<master>
```

And all the files in the folder of the app :

```
myapp2
-oscpy. 
-oscpy-0.5.0.dist-info #both files of downloaded oscpy module
-plyer
-plyer-2.0.0.dist-info #for plyer
-android.txt           #spec file
-main.py               #main file
-service.py            #service file
```

This is all the information I could provide and before packaging the apk, I'm using the Kivy Launcher to check run this app.
The error displayed in logs is:

> 

```
>stderr: jnius.jnius.JavaException: Class not found 'org/kivy/oscserv/ServicePong'
```

And the app crashes.

** It is working fine on windows.
So there seems no error with the service.py

{Again, I am new to app development and also Kivy. So I think there is probably something wrong with the use of services (the autoclass lines and the service object creation).}

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.